# How do I select a a row in openpyxl without specifying column?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to apply conditional formatting to my spreadsheet, but instead of iterating over every single cell (of which there are very many) I want to apply the formatting to the entire row.

I have been trying to figure out how to just select a row. I looked on [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html) (scroll a bit less than halfway down to 'Accessing many cells'), and it tells me

```
row10 = ws[10]
```

but when I try to do that I get the error message saying

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

which I take to mean that it is not a valid range. I messed around with it a bit, but could not make it work.

So at this point I have no idea what to do. Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: What version of openpyxl are you using?

Comment: Oh I see. Im out of date. Will get back to you after I update

Comment: Ok I updated. Now when I enter ws[10] I dont get an error, but I only selects A10 and not the entire 10 row.

Comment: Though im now realizing that perhaps if there is something that selects an entire row, it may just be iterating over every cell anyway, in which case selecting the whole excel row would be less efficient than just selecting all by data cells